# How to create a Pandas boolean column indicating if a value will have an n-fold increase in x periods ahead?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single column in a DataFrame containing only numbers, and I need to create a boolean column to indicate if the value will have an n-fold increase in x periods ahead.

I developed a solution using two for loops, but it doesn't seem pythonic enough for me.

Is there a better, more efficient way of doing it? Maybe something with map() or apply()?

Find below my code with an MRE.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,2,1,3,2,1,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,5,1], columns=['column'])

df['double_in_5_periods_ahead'] = 'n/a'
periods_ahead = 5

for i in range(0,len(df)-periods_ahead):
    for j in range(1,periods_ahead):
        if df['column'].iloc[i+j]/df['column'].iloc[i] >= 2:
            df['double_in_5_periods_ahead'].iloc[i] = 1
            break
        else:
            df['double_in_5_periods_ahead'].iloc[i] = 0
```

This is the output:

```
column  double_in_5_periods_ahead
0   1   1
1   2   0
2   2   0
3   1   1
4   3   0
5   2   1
6   1   1
7   3   0
8   4   0
9   1   1
10  2   1
11  3   n/a
12  4   n/a
13  4   n/a
14  5   n/a
15  1   n/a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try rolling

```
n = 5 
df['new']  = (df['column'].iloc[::-1].rolling(n).max() / df['column']).gt(2).astype(int)
df.iloc[-n:,1]=np.nan
df
Out[146]: 
    column  new
0        1  1.0
1        2  0.0
2        2  0.0
3        1  1.0
4        3  0.0
5        2  0.0
6        1  1.0
7        3  0.0
8        4  0.0
9        1  1.0
10       2  1.0
11       3  NaN
12       4  NaN
13       4  NaN
14       5  NaN
15       1  NaN
```